# Collapse python comment in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments

Not long ago, I started commenting a lot of code in python, the problem is that vs code does not offer me to reduce the comment.

I have tried single line comments and group comments but same issue..

[python single line comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I25At.png)
[python multiline program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzbzt.png)

In other languages for example C.. it offers me in the bar a button to collapse

[example in C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syqwl.png)

How can comment collapsing be enabled in VS?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it. I think vscode itself provides this function, but I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

As can be seen from the figure, multiline annotations can be folded.

[image]

[image]

Of course, there is no solution for your situation. We can add `#region` before the content, add `#endregion` after it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does my solution solve your issue?